# Windows phone xap supporting OS 7.0 detected as 7.1 in marketplace

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, marketplace, xap

I've created an app supporting separately **WP 7.1** and **WP 7.0** (both in VS2010).

However when I upload xap files o this app both are detected to be WP 7.1 OS. Is there a way to be specific that given xap supports WP 7.0 and WP 7.1 is supposed to be handled by the other xap?

If there is more detail required to diagnose the issue I will be happy to provide it.

At this point, I can say that I create a solution for windows phone with Visual Studio 2010, and when VS asks about OS version I choose 7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone 7.0 isn't supported anymore. Only devices running Windows Phone 7.1 and higher can access the marketplace. It explains why you can't target specifically WP7.0.

http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2012/05/22/starting-today-you-need-windows-phone-7-5-to-use-marketplace.aspx